# How to generate PDF of Grid control or Stack Panel in Windows Universal App (Windows-10)?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, windows-10

I am working on Windows Universal App. I have Sales module in my app. I want to provide PDF  functionality in my app(mobile).Can anybody suggest me how to generate PDF of default  Grid layout(Page contain)?

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [Amyuni PDF Creator UWP Controls](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a4117d8a-4f87-435d-ba24-7ae56a39591a)

[Foxit PDF SDK](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/products/sdk/register.php?product=PDFSDK) supports Modern UI. You can try it with UWP.

Comment: It is paid version. Can you suggest free version or any other solution?

Comment: Try this link with description how to creare PDF file yourself on WP. It might help you [How to generate PDF on Windows Phone in VB or C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucian/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c/)

Comment: I am  working on  windows universal app( use visual studio 2015 and windows 10) and  you provided a code for visual studio 2012 and windows 8 app but i want to add this functionality in windows 10 app so please give a solution of it.

Comment: I am using xaml so, i want to create a pdf of my xaml page in windows universal app.

Comment: @HardikKothari I know that you need UWP example. But I have give you a hint. You can convert WP8 code to UWP (may be it even doesn't need any changes). I don't know where to get free control and ready PDF export example for UWP, but hope that has help you a lot.

Comment: Its not working sir i tried a lot . can you please provide me another way to solve this problem.i want to create a PDF file of the page(Invoice.xaml)  which i designed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use ready made lib, syncfusion offer a [good solution](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/pdf) and [one components](https://www.componentone.com/Studio/Reporting-Documents/PDFUWP)

But here is a good start to create PDF yourself: http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest and https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2010/09/grow-your-own-pdf-file-part-1-pdf-objects-and-data-types/

Comment: I am on initial stage so i can't afford paid control so guide me how can i solve it .

Comment: @HardikKothari Syncfusion entire product is available for free with no limitations through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify (less than one million US Dollars in revenue per year).